# TypeError: android.widget.Button{1e209aa1VFED...C. ........} in not a valid view instance

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to use native codes in nativescript directly. am getting this error on adding the created android.widget.Button proxy in javascript to the StackLayout(which is predefined in nativescript)

> An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException:  Calling js method
>   onViewAttachedToWindow failed
>
> Error: android.widget.Button{1e209aa2 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0} is
>   not a valid View instance. File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js,
>   line: 414, column: 12
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'ViewBase._addView',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js',
>   line: 414, column: 19     Frame: function:'LayoutBaseCommon.addChild',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js',
>   line: 44, column: 14  Frame: function:'onNavigatingTo',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/main-page.js',
>   line: 15, column: 12  Frame: function:'Observable.notify',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js',
>   line: 110, column: 23     Frame: function:'PageBase.onNavigatingTo',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/page/page-common.js',
>   line: 107, column: 14     Frame: function:'FrameBase._onNavigatingTo',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js',
>   line: 276, column: 37     Frame: function:'FrameBase.performNavigation',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js',
>   line: 248, column: 14     Frame:
>   function:'FrameBase._processNextNavigationEntry',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js',
>   line: 241, column: 22     Frame:
>   function:'Frame._processNextNavigationEntry',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 143, column: 58     Frame: function:'Frame._onAttachedToWindow',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 118, column: 14     Frame:
>   function:'AttachListener.onViewAttachedToWindow',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Tekmo/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 35, column: 27
>
> at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)    at
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1120)     at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1000)   at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:987)    at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)    at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)    at
>   com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_frame_29_36_AttachListener.onViewAttachedToWindow(Object_frame_29_36_AttachListener.java:17)
>     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14835)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2989)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2997)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2997)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2997)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2997)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2997)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1573)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7057)
>     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:829)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:576)    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:815)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;

var application = require("application");
const toast = android.widget.Toast
var context = application.android.context

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = createViewModel();

    var button = new android.widget.Button(context);
    var text = "My Button"; // JavaScript string
    button.setText(text);

    var parent=page.getViewById("parent")
    parent.addChild(button)
}
```

Comment: import { Button } from "tns-core-modules/ui/button"; and var button = new Button();
button .text = "Tap me!";, Nativescript button actualy implements native button https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button

Comment: Is there any special case that you are trying to add button like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NativeScript has a [Button](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/button) component which you may directly use. If you like to access any native properties of Button then simply access the `.nativeView` on {N} button once it's loaded, this will return `android.widget.Button` while running on Android / `UIButton` in iOS.

`.addChild` excepts components built on {N} view hierarchy, if you like to add a native element to UI, you may use a [PlaceHolder](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder).